# Disable item in Combobox in DataGridViewComboBoxCell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I'd like to disable item in `ComboBox` that is in a `DataGridview` cell.

I already know how to disable(or seems disabled) items in a `ComboBox`, using the `DrawItem` event and `SelectedIndexChanged` event but there is no similar event in `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` or `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`.

**So my question** is, how to disable any item in ComboBox that is in a DataGridView?

In ComboBox I can modify items display that need to be disabled like this:
[image]

But can't do the same functionality in DataGridView:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest option for you would be to handle the [EditControlShowing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing?view=netframework-4.8) event, and then handle the ComboBoxes `SelectedIndexChanged` event and do what you already know how to do.

When you setup the `DataGridview` in code, you can do this:

```
dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing;
```

And then implement the handler like:

```
void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox combo = e.Control as ComboBox;

    if (combo != null)
    {
        // Both of these lines are essential, otherwise you will be handling the same event twice in some conditions
        combo.SelectedIndexChanged -= combo_SelectedIndexChanged;
        combo.SelectedIndexChanged += combo_SelectedIndexChanged;
    }
}
```

Finally, the `SelectedIndexChanged` event is handled exactly the way you want to:

```
void combo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox thisCombo = sender as ComboBox;
    if (thisCombo != null)
    {
        Debug.Print(thisCombo.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, seems it works, just a tiny fix, I have to tell `combo.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed` in `EditControlShowing` to let `Combo_DrawItem(object, DrawItemEventArgs)` call.